# Why doesn't my assembly struct's size match the struct size the GetOpenFileNameA function expects?

Tags: assembly, winapi, struct, masm, calling-convention

I'm trying to display an open file dialog using the Win32 API and x64 assembly. To do so, I'm matching the expected struct's memory allocations to that of the `OPENFILENAMEA` structure (in `commdlg.h`), but I seem to be off by 4 bytes, since the size of my struct is 140 bytes. The `CommDlgExtendedError()` function doesn't return `CDERR_STRUCTSIZE` (0x0001) if I manually set the `lStructSize` parameter to 136 or 152, but an "Access violation reading location 0x0000010000007FF7" error occurs instead.

I'm using MASM (`ml64.exe`) in Visual Studio 2022 Community and assembling under x64.

Here's the struct I'm trying to match (`lpEditInfo` and `lpstrPrompt` are omitted) from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea

```c
typedef struct tagOFNA {
  DWORD         lStructSize;
  HWND          hwndOwner;
  HINSTANCE     hInstance;
  LPCSTR        lpstrFilter;
  LPSTR         lpstrCustomFilter;
  DWORD         nMaxCustFilter;
  DWORD         nFilterIndex;
  LPSTR         lpstrFile;
  DWORD         nMaxFile;
  LPSTR         lpstrFileTitle;
  DWORD         nMaxFileTitle;
  LPCSTR        lpstrInitialDir;
  LPCSTR        lpstrTitle;
  DWORD         Flags;
  WORD          nFileOffset;
  WORD          nFileExtension;
  LPCSTR        lpstrDefExt;
  LPARAM        lCustData;
  LPOFNHOOKPROC lpfnHook;
  LPCSTR        lpTemplateName;
  LPEDITMENU    lpEditInfo;
  LPCSTR        lpstrPrompt;
  void          *pvReserved;
  DWORD         dwReserved;
  DWORD         FlagsEx;
} OPENFILENAMEA, *LPOPENFILENAMEA;
```

Here's my code:

```
extrn ExitProcess: PROC
extrn GetOpenFileNameA: PROC
extrn CommDlgExtendedError: PROC

.data
filename db 256 dup(0)
tagOFNA STRUCT
  lStructSize       dd 0    ; 0 - dword
  hwndOwner         dq 0    ; 4 - qword
  hInstance         dq 0    ; 12    - qword
  lpstrFilter       dq 0    ; 20    - qword
  lpstrCustomFilter dq 0    ; 28    - qword
  nMaxCustFilter    dd 0    ; 36    - dword
  nFilterIndex      dd 0    ; 40    - dword
  lpstrFile         dq offset filename  ; 44    - qword
  nMaxFile          dd 256  ; 52    - dword
  lpstrFileTitle    dq 0    ; 56    - qword
  nMaxFileTitle     dd 0    ; 64    - dword
  lpstrInitialDir   dq 0    ; 68    - qword
  lpstrTitle        dq 0    ; 76    - qword
  Flags             dd 0    ; 84    - dword
  nFileOffset       dw 0    ; 88    - word
  nFileExtension    dw 0    ; 90    - word
  lpstrDefExt       dq 0    ; 92    - qword
  lCustData         dq 0    ; 100   - qword
  lpfnHook          dq 0    ; 108   - qword
  lpTemplateName    dq 0    ; 116   - qword
  pvReserved        dq 0    ; 124   - qword
  dwReserved        dd 0    ; 132   - dword
  FlagsEx           dd 0    ; 136   - dword
tagOFNA ENDS

myofn tagOFNA <sizeof tagOFNA>

.code
main PROC
    sub rsp, 28h

    lea  rcx, myofn

    call GetOpenFileNameA

    call CommDlgExtendedError
    mov rcx, rax
    call ExitProcess
main ENDP
end
```

I've tried setting parameters for the struct, but that didn't make any difference, so I tried to get the minimal amount of code to just open the dialog, by setting every parameter to null, except the `lStructSize` and `lpstrFile` struct parameters.

Comment: It would be somewhat unusual to have misaligned qwords; are you sure there isn't padding after `DWORD     lStructSize;` to align the qword `HWND` and other later qwords which your asm has at odd multiples of 8?  (Or is `HWND` still 32-bit in x64?)  You could look at compiler-generated asm to check the struct offsets and see where member offsets differ from your asm.  (https://godbolt.org/).  e.g. write a functions that assign multiple members.  You can "binary search" to find the first member at a wrong offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Peter commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76847785/why-doesnt-my-assembly-structs-size-match-the-struct-size-the-getopenfilenamea#comment135477082_76847785), the C struct has padding for alignment. You are missing 3 dwords which bring your size from 140 to 152 as expected. You have to insert padding after the `lStructSize`, `nMaxFile` and `nMaxFileTitle` to align the following qword members to multiple of 8:

```
  lStructSize       dd 0    ; 0 - dword
  pad1              dd 0    ; 4 - dword
  hwndOwner         dq 0    ; 8 - qword
  hInstance         dq 0    ; 16    - qword
  lpstrFilter       dq 0    ; 24    - qword
  lpstrCustomFilter dq 0    ; 32    - qword
  nMaxCustFilter    dd 0    ; 40    - dword
  nFilterIndex      dd 0    ; 44    - dword
  lpstrFile         dq offset filename  ; 48    - qword
  nMaxFile          dd 256  ; 56    - dword
  pad2              dd 0    ; 60    - dword
  lpstrFileTitle    dq 0    ; 64    - qword
  nMaxFileTitle     dd 0    ; 72    - dword
  pad3              dd 0    ; 76    - dword
  lpstrInitialDir   dq 0    ; 80    - qword
  lpstrTitle        dq 0    ; 88    - qword
  Flags             dd 0    ; 96    - dword
  nFileOffset       dw 0    ; 100   - word
  nFileExtension    dw 0    ; 102   - word
  lpstrDefExt       dq 0    ; 104   - qword
  lCustData         dq 0    ; 112   - qword
  lpfnHook          dq 0    ; 120   - qword
  lpTemplateName    dq 0    ; 128   - qword
  pvReserved        dq 0    ; 136   - qword
  dwReserved        dd 0    ; 144   - dword
  FlagsEx           dd 0    ; 148   - dword
```

Comment: As a side note, MASM [`struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/struct-masm?view=msvc-170) keyword takes an alignement parameter. In this case this would be `tagOFNA STRUCT 8` (same as compiling with `/Zp8`, except the latter would apply as a default to all structs).